# Remove hamburger menu toggle when mobile menu is open

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

As per my screenshot you can see that the hamburger icon is showing along with the X (close) on the mobile menu. I want to remove the hamburger icon from showing in the active menu.[mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIMFI.png)

This is a Wordpress site. The issue began when I manually added an icon to replace the standard hamburger toggle.

```
.menu-mobile-toggle {
  display:block;   
  background-image: url("http://danielleclevy.com/wp- 
  content/uploads/2018/05/if_Hamburger_657904-1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: How was the standard hamburger icon implemented? It might be an easier approach to just overwrite whatever CSS declaration does that while leaving the rest of it alone. Or at least investigate what difference might exist between that code and your code.